# C Shell: Program hanging in first child

Tags: c, pipe, dup2

I have created a C-shell that executes commands entered by the user. One of the requirements for this shell is when handling pipe calls, the first child directs it output to the parent via pipe1 where the parent then reads the output and writes it to the second child via pipe2. The problem I am facing is that when arguments with pipe are entered, the program hangs in the first child and does not execute the argument.

The code snippet given below is the function responsible for executing pipe commands (I have marked the point where it hangs):

```
void execPipeArgs(char** befPipe, char** aftPipe, int n_reads){

  pid_t child_1, child_2;
  int pipe1[2];  // Fd for pipe1
  int pipe2[2]; // Fd for pipe2

  // Create pipe1
  if(pipe(pipe1) < 0){
    printf("%s\n", "Failure! Pipe1 not created" );
    exit(0);
  }
  // Create pipe2
  if(pipe(pipe2) < 0){
    printf("%s\n", "Failure! Pipe2 not created" );
    exit(0);
  }

  // Create first Child
  child_1 = fork();

  // Check if fork successfull
  if(child_1  < 0){
    printf("%s\n", "ERROR! CHILD 1 NOT CREATED" );
    exit(0);
  }

  // In first child
  if(child_1 == 0){
      ***"THIS IS WHERE IT HANGS"***

      dup2(pipe1[1],1);
      close(pipe1[0]);
      close(pipe2[0]);
      close(pipe2[1]);

      if(execvp(befPipe[0],befPipe) < 0){
          printf("%s\n", "Command not executed in child_1" );
          exit(0);
      }
  }

  // In PARENT
  else {
      // Wait for child_1
      wait(NULL);

      int readCalls = 0;
      int charCount = 0;
      int bytesRead = 0;
      char* byteBuffer[500];
      close(pipe1[1]);

      //Get number of bytes, read/write calls
      while((bytesRead = read(pipe1[0],byteBuffer,n_reads)) != NULL){
        readCalls++;
        charCount = charCount + bytesRead;
        //write to pipe2
        write(pipe2[1],byteBuffer,bytesRead);
      }

      // Second Child
      child_2 = fork();

      // In child_2
      if(child_2 == 0){
        dup2(pipe2[0],0);
        close(pipe2[1]);
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe1[0]);

        if(execvp(aftPipe[0],aftPipe) < 0){
            printf("%s\n", "Command not executed in child_2" );
            exit(0);
        }
      } // if child_2 end
      else{
        // In Parent
        wait(NULL);
      }
  }
} // end of execArgsPipe
```

I found similar questions here on stackoverflow but none of the solutions helped me solve my problem. The most common answer was regarding closing the pipes at the appropriate places which I have tried but my program still hangs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The other questions are giving you the hint; you aren’t closing enough pipe descriptors.  After using `dup2()` to map a pipe to stdin or stdout, you should close *both* pipe descriptors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you mean closing the pipe descriptors in the parent aswell? I have closed the pipe descriptors in the child (in the code above i closed pipe descriptors for both pipes after the dup2 call but it still hangs.) I even tried closing all file descriptors after the dup2 call but still the problem remains (Note: all close ops were done in child).

Comment: In child 2, you only close 3 of the 4 pipe descriptors.  Ditto child 1.   The parent process should probably also close all 4 pipe descriptors.    If it doesn’t close them, the child processes won’t get EOF.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have tried that too. I closed all 4 descriptors in both children and the parent, yet the still the problem remains. A printf statement just before the dup2() call in child_1 is printed but if i place it after the dup2() call its not executed.

Comment: General comments: (1) errors should be reported on `stderr` and not `stdout`; (2) when you exit because of an error, you should not use `exit(0)` but should exit with some non-zero value (in case of doubt, use `EXIT_FAILURE`); (3) you don't need to test the return from `execvp()` or any of the `exec*()` family of functions because they don't return if they're successful and only ever return on failure.

Comment: Your "this is where it hangs" comment in the code is not plausible.  The code does not hang before the `dup2()` call — or, at least, you've got a lot of talking to do to persuade me that it does.  We're going to need an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You also have multiple design issues.  There's no point in the parent reading the output from child 1 and writing it to child 2 when child1 could write direct to child 2 (unless you're also going to log the data from child1, and even then there are ways like inserting `| tee log.file` into the pipeline for tracking that).

Comment: Also, in general, the first child may produce more data than will fit in a pipe (the holding capacity of a pipe is smallish — POSIX mandates 4 KiB; classically, it was 5 KiB; it is usually 64 KiB these days, but not often more), so it will be hung waiting for the parent to read from its output, while the parent is still waiting for the child to terminate — deadlock.

Comment: The conventional way to handle `producer | consumer` is for the shell to fork 2 processes and let `producer` write to the output of the pipe and let `consumer` read from the input of the pipe, while the parent shuts down its copies of the pipe completely.  If you really want to have the parent mediate the communications, it can be done, of course.  You have the parent create the two pipes, fork both children, and then it sits in a loop reading from the output of child 1 and writing to the input of child 2.  In this case, the parent closes two of the pipe descriptors, not all four.

Comment: The pipe creation must be done before the processes that will use it are created. Within the description above, there are different ways to handle the children.  Child 1 could fork to create child 2, or the parent can create both child 1 and child 2.  There are minor differences in the necessary plumbing.  If the parent directly creates both children, the second pipe might be created after the first child is forked; in that case, there's no second pipe for the first child to close.  Etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for you answer. You were correct in pointing out that i needed to close the correct fds in parent. Turns out I wasnt closing the write end of pipe2 after the loop in the parent. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that child_1 hangs ? Is it because you had tried adding prints but did not see anything on stdout? As per dup2 man page, *'dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary'*. Hence stdout in child_1 is now a copy of pipe1[1]. So any print statement inside child_1 will not be displayed on your screen.

You may check out this link as well:
[Pipe implementation stuck at dup2 command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584730/pipe-implementation-stuck-at-dup2-command)

Comment: Had missed the last couple comments from @JonathanLeffler. Good that you already found the issue. :)